# What is the use of giving name of chatbot?

Tags: chatterbot

I started writing scripts for my own chatbot and i have one basic question which i could not solve using available documentation. While defining chatbot instance, we give a name of the chatbot. (Something like below):

bot = ChatBot(
        'John',
        logic_adapters = [
                 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch']

Here, can we use this name 'John' anyhow like calling some functions with it or displaying it somewhere? or it is only for information purpose?Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my code which does what you want:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

def bot(title, read_only = True):    # , don't learn from exchanges (responses exist)
    Bot = ChatBot(title,
                   #filters=["chatterbot.filters.RepetitiveResponseFilter"],
                   logic_adapters=[{                       
                       'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
                       "statement_comparision_function": "chatterbot.comparisions.levenshtein_distance",
                       "response_selection_method": "chatterbot.response_selection.get_first_response"
                       }])
    print('Training corpus',title)
    trainer=ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(Bot)
    trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english." + title)     
    return Bot                                         # trained instance

bots = {}
# check what corpora available and traina a bot for each one
for item in os.listdir('C:/Python/Python38/lib/site-packages/chatterbot_corpus/data/english/'):
    corpus = item.split('.')        # of the form 'item.yml'
    name = corpus[0]
    bots[name]= bot(name)  # add bot instance to dictionary of available bots
                                                        
def exchange(input):  # let's get a response to our input
    bot = bots[context]
    response = bot.get_response(input)
```